# How to use contextlib.contextmanager with a classmethod?

Tags: python, class-method, contextmanager

See the below Python 3.10 snippet:

```py
import contextlib

class Foo:
    @contextlib.contextmanager
    @classmethod
    def state(cls):
        try:
            yield
        finally:
            pass

with Foo.state():
    pass
```

It throws a `TypeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/code/play/quick_play.py", line 12, in <module>
    with Foo.state():
  File "/path/to/.pyenv/versions/3.10.5/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 281, in helper
    return _GeneratorContextManager(func, args, kwds)
  File "/path/to/.pyenv/versions/3.10.5/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 103, in __init__
    self.gen = func(*args, **kwds)
TypeError: 'classmethod' object is not callable
```

Is it possible to decorate a `classmethod` with [`contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager)?  And if yes, how can it be done?

Comment: Just reverse the two decorators.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731811/how-can-i-mix-decorators-with-the-contextmanager-decorator

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```py
import contextlib

class Foo:
    @classmethod
    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def state(cls):
        try:
            print("A")
            yield
            print("C")
        finally:
            pass

with Foo.state():
    print("B")
```

This prints A B C.